# Why Linked List is called Linked List

Tags: javascript, data-structures, linked-list

I was explaining basic data structure to a non-programmer. And I explained that an array or list is a collection. For example, an array is a collection of numbers, names or things: a pencil box where there are many pencils.

After explaining lists, I tried to explain linked lists, describing them as something where lists are connected (linked). However in most of the examples for linked lists, I don’t see lists getting connected. rather objects or nodes get linked.

My question is: why it is called “linked list”? Why not “linked nodes” or “linked object”?

Comment: Well, from the Wiki page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), 
 "Linked lists are among the simplest and most common data structures. They can be used to implement several other common abstract data types, including lists (the abstract data type), stacks, queues, associative arrays, and S-expressions, though it is not uncommon to implement the other data structures directly without using a list as the basis of implementation."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically a list is a collection type that allows you to get elements by a position or insert elements into specific positions.

A list can be implemented using an array internally and is typically called "array list". It can also be implemented as a sequence of linked (or most likely doubly linked) elements, and would be called "linked list".

Another example would be a set; it could be a hashed set of elements when the order does not matter or a tree set that keeps element in a sorted order.

Comment: I see... Items of a list are linked and that's why it's called linked list.

Answer (score 2):

It is a shorthand for a list made up of linked items. A linked braking system is created from linking front and rear brakes, which makes the system. Here linking the items makes the list.